# Do CSS rules exist for placing content within elements and positioning them?

Tags: css, background-image, styling, css-content

Do CSS rules exist for placing content such as images or text within elements?

eg. say I have a div which can contain some info which is correct and some info which is wrong, can I have rules such as:

```
.correct {
  img: greenTick.jpg;
  text: "answer is wrong"
}

.wrong {
  img: redX.jpg;
  text: "answer is correct"
}
```

Is it possible to position them too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) ([`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)). Set the text using the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) attribute, and the image as the [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) of the pseudo element or the `div`:

```css
.correct::before {
  padding: 1em;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/100);
  background-size: contain;
  color: white;
  content: "answer is correct"
}

.wrong::before {
  padding: 1em;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200);
  background-size: contain;
  color: white;
  content: "answer is wrong"
}
```

```html
<div class="correct"></div>

<br><br>

<div class="wrong"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS `background-image` attribute would be the one that you need to use instead `img`. See below an example of how to do it with your both style classes:

```
.correct {
    background-image: url("greenTick.jpg");
}

.wrong {
    background-image: url("redX.jpg");
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the image not just to be a background-image, but set its size and position as well?